# Confusion on independent variables and prediction

Tags: time-series, random-variable, mutual-information

Suppose $X_{i}$ is an i.i.d random variable for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. Since $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ are independent for all $i \neq j$, the mutual information $I(X_{i}, X_{j}) = 0$.

If $X_{i}$ has sequential order (e.g. time series), does it mean that it is impossible to predict $X_{t}$ at time $t = T$ even if we know $X_{t}$ for all time $t < T$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the distribution of $X_T$ conditional on all past values is the same as its marginal distribution. Therefore, the conditional expectation is the same as the unconditional expectation.

So it is impossible to improve upon the unconditional "prediction", which is simply the unconditional expectation $E(X_T)$, with observations of past values.